# Java MalformedUrlException

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to download a file from url but if url doesn't exist something works wrong.

My first solution:

```
            try {
                saveUrl("temp.pgm",webAdress.getText());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

saveUrl method:

```
 public void saveUrl(final String filename, final String urlString)
                throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            BufferedInputStream in = null;
            FileOutputStream fout = null;
            try {
                in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
                fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

                final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                int count;
                while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                    fout.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } finally {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (fout != null) {
                    fout.close();
                }
            }
        }
```

if I put random string in webAdress (for example "asdasdasd") exception doesn't work and error is:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: ghghjghj
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at pl.edu.pwr.pp.LoadActivity.saveUrl(LoadActivity.java:254)
    at pl.edu.pwr.pp.LoadActivity$5.actionPerformed(LoadActivity.java:179)
```

I tried another solution but there is the same problem:

```
File pathToTmpFile = new File("tmpfile.pgm");                
                            try {
                                FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(webAdress.getText()), pathToTmpFile);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        pathToTmpFile.delete();
```

I have no idea why exception doesn't work (if url exits file is downloaded).

Comment: Well that's the way it should work. If you have a malformed URL then a MalformedUrlException should be thrown upon construction of an URL-object. So what is your problem?

Comment: It's working correctly, you do not catch the malformed url exception, so it ends up in the printstacktrace.

Comment: Actually he does, Malformed Url is a an IOException, so it should be caught. The stack is printed because of the "e.printStackTrace();".

Comment: MalformedURLException is not an error but an exception. So what is the problem? What do you mean with it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea why exception doesn't work

It did work. The user entered `ghghjghj:` ... something, and you got an entirely appropriate exception.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have to catch `MalformedURLException` inside `try-catch` block in `saveURL` method or you will have remove try-catch block from `saveURL` method.

Try following code segment.

```
try {
      in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(urlString).openStream());
      fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);

      final byte data[] = new byte[1024];
      int count;
      while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
        fout.write(data, 0, count);
      }
} catch(IOException ioe) {
      throw ioe; //Propogation of exception
} finally {
      if (in != null) {
        in.close();
      }

      if (fout != null) {
        fout.close();
      }
}
```